# not able to update variable onkeyup javascript

Tags: onkeyup

I have a textarea and i want to update a javascript variable onkeyup for textarea.

Here is my code:

```
 <textarea id="q" name="q"></textarea>
 <button onclick='alert(rec);'>
 Click
 </button>
<script>
var rec;

$("#q").keyup(function(){
      rec = document.getElementById("q").value;
});
</script>
```

i've implemented jquery , of course.

https://jsfiddle.net/wvsc93d4/

Comment: Actually your should also work, just set in JSFiddle to load JQuery lib as you are using it, and to append the script to the body element.

Comment: Here is yours without code change, just included jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/wvsc93d4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$("#q").keyup(function(){
      rec = $('#q').val();
});
```

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/wvsc93d4/1/

Comment: Can you tell me why with the same structure, this does not work? https://jsfiddle.net/wvsc93d4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. You were just trying to call rec before it was set.

```js
var rec = "";

$("#q").keyup(function(){
      rec = document.getElementById("q").value;
});

$("#showMe").on("click", function(){
console.log(rec);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="q" name="q"></textarea>
 <button id="showMe">
 Click
 </button>
```

Comment: Can you tell me why with the same structure, this does not work? jsfiddle.net/wvsc93d4/3

Comment: you forgot to put the # in front of the $("email").attr("href",email); Should be $("#email).attr("href", email);

Comment: also, you might want to add the http:// with your www.corriere.it link.